# Force img to be exact height/width in bootstrap 2

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-2

I am using bootstrap 2 and I have a nav span on the left side of my page.  That span contains a list of users.  I would like to place a thumbnail of the users avatar along side the users information(username, first and last name)

```
<div class="container">  
    <div class="row-fluid">   
        <div class="span3">
           <div class="row-fluid">
                <div class="span3">
                  <img class="img-rounded" width="75" height="75" src="http://placehold.it/400x200"/>
                </div>
                <div class="span9">
                  <div class="strong">bbthornton</div>
                  <div class="muted">Billy Bob Thornton</div>
                </div>
          </div>
          <div class="row-fluid">
                <div class="span3">
                  <img class="img-rounded" width="75" height="75" src="http://placehold.it/200x400"/>
                </div>
                <div class="span9">
                  <div class="strong">mtyson</div>
                  <div class="muted">Mike Tyson</div>
                </div>
          </div>
        </div>
    <div>
    <div class="span9">
       Other Content
    </div>
</div>
```

The server I hit to get the users avatar does not force the users avatar to be square.  Is there a way that I can force those images to be square and say 75x75?

Here is a fiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/newmanw/htbu7sno/1/

Also wondering if you can somehow not lose original aspect ratio. That would require a crop as well. Not sure how much you can do with just css.  The thumbs are small enough that if I didn't maintain the aspect ratio it might not look too bad.

Answer (score 0):

Control the images' size through CSS.  As you see here: http://jsfiddle.net/htbu7sno/4/

I added a class to the image element: avatar, and set the width and height there:

```
.avatar{
    width: 75px;
    height: 75px;
}
```

this will resize the image, but will **not** maintain the aspect ratio.

If you want to maintain the aspect ratio, you can always surround the img tag with a container, size the container and set the overflow property to "hidden", like so:

http://jsfiddle.net/htbu7sno/6/

HTML:

```
<div class="img-container">
    <img class="img-rounded"  src="http://placehold.it/400x200"/>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.img-container{
    width: 75px;
    height: 75px;
    overflow: hidden;
    border-radius: 5px;
}
```

Either way has its pros and cons.  The first instance won't maintain aspect ratio, but the second (as you can see in the second jsFiddle), might make the image smaller than the container.

Comment: So with 2 examples, one sets size to square and does not maintain aspect ratio.  Second mantains aspect ratio but size is not square.  Possible to get both?

Comment: I may be wrong, but with CSS alone there may be no better option.  Is this strictly html/CSS or are you using a server-side language as well?  Also, are you in control of the images being uploaded?

Answer (score 0):

Use maximum width to keep the aspect ratio of width.

**[Here is the jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/talves/dchjn4x1/)**

```htm
<div class="img-container">
  <img class="img-rounded"  src="http://placehold.it/400x200"/>
</div>
```

```css
.img-container {
    height: 75px;
    width: 75px;
    overflow: hidden;
    -webkit-border-radius: 6px;
    -moz-border-radius: 6px;
    border-radius: 6px;
}
.img-container img.img-rounded {
    min-width: 75px;
    max-width: 75px;
}
```

**NOTE:** If you want to solve the issue of resolving the aspect ratio of a minimum height and width at the same time, it will not be able to be solved with css alone.

Comment: But the images are still different sizes.  I want to maintain aspect ratio and give images a square size.  Possible?

Comment: What do you want the origin position to be?  The top right corner?